# What is negative value for width or height?

Tags: android

What is the purpose of such code:

```
android:layout_height="-2"
```

Or

```
android:layout_width="-1"
```

How should I interpret such values? Are they in connection to layout_weight attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:
My mistake, I misunderstood the question.

The negative values seem to represent match_parent, wrap_content, and fill_parent.

When -1 or -2 is applied, the view fills the screen just as it would for match_parent or fill_parent.  When any number -3 or lower is applied, the behavior is the same as wrap_content.

The values are not related to the layout_weight, just the pre-defined constants for width and height in Android.

Comment: AS it is currently written, your code produces errors for me in Eclipse.  android:layout_width="-1" is invalid.  I assumed you meant something like android:layout_width="-1dp" for the purposes of my answer.